# Size-Biased Galton Watson Tree.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, martingales

First of all, i am not sure whether this question belongs here or to stack overflow. Let me write here, first, i will give a definition of size-biased distribution. then i will give definition of size-biased Galton-Watson Tree that is defined by Lyons, Pemantle and Peres [1995]. Warning: A lot of part is taken from lecture notes of Zhan Shi(Random Walks and Trees).   Let $\nu $ be a distribution on $(\mathbb{R}^{+},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{+}))$ with finite and positive mean $\gamma= \int x \nu(dx)=\int x d\nu $. Then the distribution  $\widehat{\nu}$ , defined by

\begin{equation*}
\widehat{\nu}(B)=\dfrac{1}{\gamma}\int_{B} x \nu(dx), \;\; B\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{+})
\end{equation*}
is called the size-biasing of $\nu$ or size-biased distribution associated with $\nu$. Given a random variable X with distribution $\nu$, any random variable $\widehat{X}$  with distribution $\widehat{\nu}$ is called a size-biasing of X.

Or the discrete case, you are usually familiar with this.If $X^{*}$ denotes the size-biasing of a random variable $X$
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{P}(X^{*}=k) = \dfrac{k \mathbb{P}(X=k)}{\mathbb{E}[X]}
\end{equation*} 
now, $\textbf{Size-biased Galton-Watson trees: construction and
properties:}$. Let $\Omega$  be the space of all trees. We now endow it with a sigma-algebra. For any $u \in \mathcal{U}$ , let $\Omega_{u}:=\lbrace w\in \Omega: u\in \omega  \rbrace $  denote the subspace of $\Omega $ consisting of all the trees containing $u$ as a vertex. [In particular, $\Omega_{\varnothing}=\Omega$ because all the trees contain the root as a vertex.]The promised sigma-algebra associated with $\Omega$ is defined by
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{F}:=\sigma\lbrace\Omega_{u},u\in \mathcal{U} \rbrace
\end{equation*}

Let $\mathbb{T}  :\Omega \rightarrow \Omega$ be the identity application.
Let $(p_{k}, k \geq 0)$ be a probability. According to Neveu [1986], there exists a probability $\mathbb{P}$ on $\Omega$ such that the law of $\mathbb{T}$ under $\mathbb{P}$ is the law of the Galton–Watson tree with reproduction distribution $(p_{k})$.
Let $\mathcal{F}_{n} := \sigma \lbrace u \in \mathcal{U}, |u|\leq n \rbrace $, where $|u|$ is the length of $u$ (representing the generation of the vertex u in the language of trees). Note that $\mathcal{F}$ is the smallest sigma-field containing every $\mathcal{F}_{n}$.

For any tree $\omega \in \Omega$ , let $Z_{n}(\omega)$ be the number of individuals in the $n$-th generation. It is easily checked that for any $n$, $Z_{n}$ is a random variable taking values in $\mathbb{N} := \lbrace 0,1,2 \ldots \rbrace$.

Let $\widehat{P}$ be the probability on ($\Omega,\mathcal{F} $) such that for any $n$
\begin{equation*}
\widehat{P}_{|\mathcal{F}_{n}}= W_{n}\bullet\mathbb{P}_{|\mathcal{F}_{n}}
\end{equation*}
i.e. $\widehat{P}(A)=\int_{A}W_{n}d\mathbb{P}$ for any $A\in \mathcal{F}_{n}$. Here $\mathbb{P}_{|\mathcal{F}_{n}}$ and $\widehat{P}_{|\mathcal{F}_{n}}$ are restrictions of $\mathbb{P}$ and $\widehat{P} $ on $\mathcal{F}_{n}$, respectively. Since $W_{n}$ is a martingale, the existence of $\widehat{P}$ is guaranteed by Kolmogorov's extension theorem. For any $n$,
\begin{equation*}
\widehat{P}(Z_{n}>0)=\int_{\lbrace Z_{n}>0\rbrace}W_{n}d\mathbb{P}= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{\lbrace Z_{n}>0\rbrace}W_{n}]=\mathbb{E}[W_{n}]=1
\end{equation*}
Therefore, $\widehat{P}(Z_{n}>0, \forall n)=1 $. In other words, there is almost surely non-extinction of the Galton–Watson tree $\mathbb{T}$ under the new probability $\widehat{P}$. The Galton–Watson tree $\mathbb{T}$ under $\widehat{P}$ called a size-biased Galton-Watson tree ($\widehat{\textbf{GW}}$). Let us give a description of its paths.

Let $N:=N_{\emptyset}$. If $N\geq 1$, then there are N individuals in the first generation. We write $\mathbb{T}_{1}$, $\mathbb{T}_{2}$, $
\ldots$, $\mathbb{T}_{1}$ for the $N$ subtrees rooted at each of the $N$ individual in the first generation.

Let $k\geq 1$. If $A_{1},A_{2},\ldots, A_{k}$ are elements of $\mathcal{F}$, then 
\begin{equation}
\widehat{P}(N=k, \mathbb{T}_{1}\in A_{1},\mathbb{T}_{2}\in A_{2},\ldots, \mathbb{T}_{k}\in A_{k})=\dfrac{kp_{k}}{m}\dfrac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k}\mathbb{P}(A_{1})\ldots\mathbb{P}(A_{i-1})\widehat{P}(A_{i})\mathbb{P}(A_{i+1})\ldots\mathbb{P}(A_{k})
\end{equation}
This equation tells us the following fact about the size-biased Galton–Watson tree ($\widehat{\textbf{GW}}$): The root has the biased distribution, i.e., having $k$ children with probability $\frac{kp_{k}}{m}$ ($\mathbb{P}(X=k)=p_{k}$) ; among the individuals in the first generation, one of them is chosen randomly (according to the uniform distribution) such that the subtree rooted at this vertex is a size-biased Galton–Watson tree ($\widehat{\textbf{GW}}$), whereas the subtrees rooted at all other vertices in the first generation are independent copies of the usual Galton–Watson tree.

Iterating the procedure, we obtain a decomposition of the size-biased Galton–Watson tree ($\widehat{\textbf{GW}}$) with an (infinite) spine and with i.i.d. copies of the usual Galton–Watson tree: The root $\emptyset=:\omega_{0}$ which is viewed as the ancestor of a given population  has the biased distribution, i.e., having k children with probability $\frac{kp_{k}}{m}$. Among the children of the root, one of them is chosen randomly (according to the uniform distribution) as the element of the spine in the first generation (denoted by $\omega_{1}$). We attach subtrees rooted at all other children; these subtrees are independent copies of the usual Galton– Watson tree. This vertex (individual) vertex $\omega_{1}$ has the biased distribution. We attach subtrees rooted at all other children; these subtrees are independent copies of the usual Galton– Watson tree.  Among the children of $\omega_{1}$, we choose at random one of them as the element of the spine in the second generation (denoted by $\omega_{2}$). Independent copies of the usual Galton–Watson tree are attached as subtrees rooted at all other children of $\omega_{1}$, whereas $\omega_{2}$ has the biased distribution and so on. As a result, we obtain random tree $\widehat{\textbf{GW}}$ with distinguished  infinite path (spine) $S=(\omega_{n})_{n\geq 1}$.

My struggle, I understood the proof Kesten-Stigum Theorem.However, my questions are 1.Why we take $\frac{kp_{k}}{m}$ instead, can we take  $\frac{k^{2}p_{k}}{\mathbb{E}[X^{2}]}$ ? what makes it special.  intuition, i know  we can't take this otherwise  $\mathbb{E}[Z\log Z ]$ characterization would be meaningless. i couldn't see any flaw in the theorem if i change $\frac{kp_{k}}{m}$ to  $\frac{k^{2}p_{k}}{\mathbb{E}[X^{2}]}$
$\textbf{Thanks in advance. I am so sorry for taking your time.}$

Comment: ?? We do not "take" $kp_k/m$, the theorem states (for example) that the distribution of the degree $N_0$ of the origin under $\hat P$ is given by $\hat P(N_0=k)=kp_k/m$ (and nothing else).

Comment: @Did ok thanks. so my question is can we define 'size-biased' Galton-Watson tree with infinite spine(path) with distribution  $k^{2}p_{k}/\mathbb{E}[X^{2}]$.

Comment: may i ask another question, for the proof of Kesten-Stigum they introduce size-biased GWT, then for the technical reasons it is more convenient to connect size-biased Galton–Watson trees with Galton–Watson branching processes with immigration. I got it. but only thing they do is to get normal GWT with infinite path(but with $kp_{k}/m$ distribution). can we take GWT with infinite path with another distribution.

Comment: One can define a tree with a spine where every vertex on the spine has any distribution one wants and every other vertex has another distribution but the result will neither be size-biased nor Galton-Watson.

Comment: ok I got my answer. but still it is not so clear for me. Why we have a problem in the proof of Kesten-Stigum if we take distribution of spine $k^{2}p_{k}/\mathbb{E}[X^{2}]$ and other children are normal GWT as defined above in the definition. I couldn't find it anywhere. i need some help. sorry if i am asking silly questions.

Comment: We do not have "a problem in the proof of KS if we take this distribution of spine" because we do not *choose* the distribution of spine we want. The distribution of (the number of descendants of the vertices in) the spine is *imposed* by the model (and the fact that it is the size-biased distribution is a part of the theorem).

Comment: @Did May i clarify what i understand with your permission. Kesten-Stigum says. Assume $1<m<\infty$. Then TFAE
\begin{align} 
\mathbb{E}[W]=1 \\
\mathbb{P}(W>0|\text{non-extinction} )=1  \\ 
\mathbb{E}\left[ Z_{1}\log Z_{1} \right] = \sum_{n\geq 0} p_{n}n\log n < \infty  (ZlogZ)
\end{align} 
To prove this we introduced size-biased GWT with infinite spine($kp_{k}/m$ distr.) and then for technicality we used GWP with immigration. so we get ZlogZ condition. but as you said if $k^{2}p_{k}/\mathbb{E}[X^{2}]$ will not make any problem then don't we have $Z^{2}$logZ condition ?

Comment: Once again the distribution $k^2p_k/E(Z^2)$ is irrelevant because conditioning by the non-extinction causes the creation of a spine where the distribution is $kp_k/E(Z)$ **and no other distribution**. This is not a choice.